# What is libusc.so and why do I get crashes from there?

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, java-native-interface

So, I'm in google play console, and I'm seeing some crashes from this mysterious `libusc.so` file. Specifically, here's the details when I open up the crash

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.myapp.blah <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000000be18  /vendor/lib/libusc.so
  #01  pc 000000000005938b  /vendor/lib/libusc.so
```

1. What does this mean? is this some 3rd party vendor firmware crash?
2. How do I get it to show up the line of the crash and the actual reason for the crash?
3. Is this even accurate on google play? Or are google play store crashes not accurate?

Comment: A quick search shows a possible lead with: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/ti/omap4-aah/+/jb-mr1-dev-plus-aosp/sgx/lib/libusc.so which implies graphics driver It would help to know if your app does anything intensive with the graphics (game or image processing).

Comment: there's some custom renderings. but how do you go about even figuring out what to do to track it down?

Comment: If you can get the device you can try to reproduce. Otherwise its the usual how many crashes out of your user audience and is it worth it.